# Ember link-to doesn't match if

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, conditional-statements, link-to

I for the life of my can't figure out why this isn't working

```
{{#if params.link}}
    {{#link-to params.link}}
        {{fa-icon icon=params.icon}}
        {{#if params.label.left}}<span class="label label-left">{{params.label.left}}</span><i class="triangle triangle-right"></i>{{/if}}
        {{#if params.text}}<span class="text">{{params.text}}</span>{{/if}}
        {{#if params.label.right}}<i class="triangle triangle-left"></i><span class="label label-right">{{params.label.right}}</span>{{/if}}{{/if}}
    {{/link-to}}
{{else}}
    <button {{action params.action}}>
        {{fa-icon icon=params.icon}}
        {{#if params.label.left}}<span class="label label-left">{{params.label.left}}</span><i class="triangle triangle-right"></i>{{/if}}
        {{#if params.text}}<span class="text">{{params.text}}</span>{{/if}}
        {{#if params.label.right}}<i class="triangle triangle-left"></i><span class="label label-right">{{params.label.right}}</span>{{/if}}{{/if}}
    </button>
{{/if}}
```

Using ember `2.2.0`, ember-data `2.2.0` and ember-cli `1.13.13`

If someone can help me fix this issue that would be great! Also the code duplication bothers me, thoughts on how I could clean this up? (maybe other than making a component?)

Comment: what is value of `params.link` ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a double `{{/if}}` at the end of the line with `{{params.label.right}}` in it. That might be the issue.

You could extract that chunk of code into a component, that would eliminate the code duplication.

Comment: You could also create an action instead of using link-to, then in your action's code you would just transition to whatever link is provided but I think that's trickier than what you're doing.